# how to save without overwriting inside a for loop

Tags: matlab

I am using a tiff image which has 1000 frames. To track the position of the object from one frame to another, I have located the centre and radius of the objects. now I need to assign the number of the frame where  its repeation inside the for loop is equal to the length obviously equally to set of centre points at a particular frame. But after the repmat the last iteration value is only saved ie., 1000

```
clear
% number of images in one TIFF file
numimgs=size(imfinfo('C:\Users\user\Desktop\Photometrics_2x bin_video2.tif'),1);
centreDark = [];
radiiDark = [];
frame=[];
for FR=1:numimgs

    %To read in all images in TIFF-file
    output_image2=imread('C:\Users\user\Desktop\Photometrics_2x bin_video2.tif',FR);
    output_image3=double(output_image2);
    disp(num2str(FR))


    ii=output_image3 - meanImage;
    %ii=im2double(meanImage-filename)

    I2 = mat2gray(ii);

    qq=fibermetric(I2, 38,'ObjectPolarity','Bright');

    %Apply Hough circular transform

    [centreDark1, radiiDark1]=imfindcircles(qq, [Rmin Rmax],'Sensitivity',0.87,'ObjectPolarity','bright');


    centreDark = [centreDark;centreDark1];
    size(centreDark)
    radiiDark = [ radiiDark;radiiDark1];
    size(radiiDark)


    frame=repmat(FR,1,size(centreDark(:,1)))
    fr=frame(:)
    %%%%fr{:,FR}=frame(:) 

end
%Table
T1= array2table(centreDark,'VariableNames',{'centreX','centreY'});
T2=array2table(radiiDark, 'VariableNames',{'Radius'});
T3=array2table(frame, 'VariableNames',{'Frame'});
% FR=fillmissing(T3,'previous');
T=[T1,T2,T3]*
```

*

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to do, what you want stored from each iteration and where (in which variable). Why does is this `fr{:,FR}=frame(:)` commented out? Does it not work? If it does, it should also probably be initialized before the loop. Something like `fr = cell(numimgs,1);`.

Comment: `FR` is a single number (your loop-counter). In the last iteration, it is equal to `numimgs`. The size of `centreDark` is something like `1000,1` (depents on how many objects are detected). So your `repmat` call is `repmat(numimgs, 1, 1000, 1)`. You ask Matlab to repeat `numimgs` whatever the size of `centreDark` is.